# AWS data quality not getting results when job name contains a "/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, data-quality

I changed my job from being job.py to be in my_folder/job.py in the bucket where AWS reads all jobs. And that caused that I can no longer see the results of the dataquality executions.

I want to understand how are related the DQ results and each job.
This is when i use  "EvaluateDataQuality().process_rows..."

Edit: added picture of desire view of dq results
[image: dq results in aws]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that it was an error from AWS that was solved! :D